# How Do You Configure JCompilo with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build, build.gradle, tail-recursion

I have an existing Gradle project with standard project layout:

`src/main/java` and `src/test/java` for my code.  I wrote the following test to confirm jcompilo was working in my project.

```
import com.googlecode.totallylazy.annotations.tailrec;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TailRecursionTest {

   @tailrec
   public static int safeRecursiveAdd(int iterations,int accumulator)  {
     if(iterations < 2)
        return accumulator;
     else{
        return safeRecursiveAdd(iterations - 1, accumulator + iterations);
     }
   }

   public static int unSafeRecursiveAdd(int iterations,int accumulator)  {
     if(iterations < 2)
        return accumulator;
     else{
        return unSafeRecursiveAdd(iterations - 1, accumulator + iterations);
     }
   }

   int STACKOVERFLOW_QUANTITY = 1000000;

   @Test(expected = StackOverflowError.class)
   public void withoutTailRecFail(){
    unSafeRecursiveAdd(STACKOVERFLOW_QUANTITY,0);
   }

   @Test
   public void tailRecWorks(){
    safeRecursiveAdd(STACKOVERFLOW_QUANTITY, 0);
   }
}
```

It fails with a StackOverflowError in the tailRecWorks() test.

My build.gradle has the following tidbits:

```
repositories {
 maven {url "http://repo.bodar.com"}
}

dependencies {
    compile group:'com.googlecode.jcompilo', name:'jcompilo', version:'2.30'
}
```

And I copied the `jcompilo.sh` file from the [totallylazy](https://github.com/bodar/totallylazy) Github master branch to the top level of the Gradle project.  I noticed in the jcompilo Github, his project layout has `src` and `test` at the top level of the project and directly contains the source code (where as mine is `src/main/java`.  I think this may be a contributing factor, but I don't know how to configure jcompilo.sh  Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I'm the JCompilo author]

JCompilo is currently mainly designed to replace Gradle completely, i.e I use JCompilo to build my other opensource tools instead of Gradle/Ant/Maven.

I have been talking to some of the Gradle/Buck developers about being able to use the JCompilo compiler directly from within Grade but unfortunately it is all just talk at the moment.

Sorry this is not the answer you were looking for.